# Active Parent CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar with several levels. Now I'm trying to make it possible to have the parent of a `li` to be active when the `li` itself is active as well.

What I've got:
https://gyazo.com/32f1191aeaf1ec3ef312de2a029eddda

As you can see, the `relations` tab is now active. So what I want is the office tab to have the same red color as well (just an example).

I hope there's a CSS only solution, since I know there's a solution for the `hover` state (`li:hover > a`). I'm using a clickable menu by the way, that's why I'm adding `.active` classes to the clicked `li`.

The active `li` would be something like: `ul li ul li.active a { color: red }`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not add `.active` to the parent `li`, and then make the child elements inherit the styles?

Comment: As Vucko said, this could be a CSS-only approach, and as Animatio said, you cannot select up the DOM, to do such magic you'll need JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS it's only possible set rules in parent > child direction. But not child > parent. In current case you can set handlers for clicks on parent and child in order to add/remove active classes. But you have to use JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 1):

Css doesn't have parent selector. You can't do this. Use js.